# Creating a larger flip-side view for 'tile' in storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, core-animation, core-graphics, storyboard

I currently have a Container View Controller which is home to a button. When this is pressed, I want the view to flip and grow, similar to iTunes on the iPad.

**Main View Controller Layout:**

[image]

**Flipping the Container:**

When the flip button is pressed, I intend to use this code (Inside the container view's View Controller) to flip the container:

```
FrontVC *cb = [[FrontVC alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 92, 65)];
FlipVC *cf = [[FlipVC alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 92, 65)];

 [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{

                    // Remove last view
                    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
                        [subview removeFromSuperview];
                    }
                    [self.view addSubview:(displayingPrimary ? cb: cf)];

                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
                        displayingPrimary = !displayingPrimary;
                    }
                }];
```

This works well if the two views are the same size, and I can lay out the views using code. FrontVC and FlipVC are sub-classes of UIView.

I was thinking about doing something like this to move the view to the centre of the screen, but I'm stuck from there. Hey, I don't even know if this would work! **Is there a better way to do this?**

```
if (!displayingPrimary) {
                        self.view.center = CGPointMake(320.0f, 480.0f);
                        cb.center = CGPointMake(320.0f, 480.0f);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.view.center = CGPointMake(59, 324);
                    }
```

**What I Am Aiming For:**

Ideally, I would like to be able to design the flip view in storyboard, and have the 'tile' grow, similar to iTunes:

[image: iTunes Flip]

Whereas in my example I would like it to look like this:

[image: My Desired Outcome]

**How would I be able to design this in storyboard?** If I try to make a view controller, I am unable to resize it to the size that I would like the flip size view controller to be.

Comment: Can you clarify if the storyboard answer is part of your request? I don't know or use Storyboards so cannot possibly reply to that, but then code to do the animation, that's a different issue.

Comment: @DavidH If you add a generic reply, i'll see if I can adapt it to work with storyboard. If so, i'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: Great - finishing up another bounty project, so will get to this in a day or two :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FlipView](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60414145/FlipView.zip) project is quite polished and looks exactly as the iTunes flip does. I used two imageViews for the demo project. The actual flip code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)flip
{
    UIView *fromView, *toView;
    CGPoint pt;
    CGSize size;
    CGFloat sense;

    if(showingView == a) {
        fromView = a;
        toView = b;
        pt = BORIGIN;
        size = BRECT.size;
        sense = -1;
    } else {
        fromView = b;
        toView = a;
        pt = AORIGIN;
        size = ARECT.size;
        sense = 1;
    }

 [UIView animateWithDuration:TIME/2 animations:^
    {
        CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
        t.m34 = M34;
        t = CATransform3DRotate(t, M_PI_2*sense, 0, 1, 0);

        containerView.layer.transform = t;
        containerView.frame = CRECT; // midpoint
        NSLog(@"Container MID Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(containerView.frame));
    }
    completion:^(BOOL isFinished)
    {
        toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI*sense, 0, 1, 0);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:TIME/2 animations:^
            {
                [fromView removeFromSuperview];
                [containerView addSubview:toView];

                CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
                t.m34 = M34;
                t = CATransform3DRotate(t, M_PI*sense, 0, 1, 0);

                containerView.layer.transform = t; //finish the flip
                containerView.frame = (CGRect){ pt, size};
            } completion:^(BOOL isFinished)
            {
                    NSLog(@"Container Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(containerView.frame));
                    NSLog(@"A Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(b.frame));
                    NSLog(@"B Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(b.frame));

                    toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    containerView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    showingView = showingView == a ? b : a;
            }];
    }];

}
```

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60414145/FlipView.zip

EDIT: One way to work around the resizing a real view with real controls in it might have is to take a snapshot of that view, use the snapshot while zooming/flipping, and in the final completion block switch out the image for the real view. That is:

- create a UIImage of your current small view when the user taps the image
- create a UIImage of the final view, rendered into a context as its natural size
- use the two images in the container view, for the animation
- in the final completion block, remove your imageView from view and put the second view now in self.view subviews

Comment: Just a quick one... The image is seen to scale as the view resizes. Would there be a way to resize the frame with, say, a block colour, then fade the image in?

Comment: You have to play around with the autoResizeMask and/or image contentMode options. I too saw this but was unsure of what you desired content was going to be - if its images I can probably tweak what I uploaded. You should be able to fade the image in too. Set the contentView.backgroundColor, and then set the imageView alpha to 0 to start with and make it 1 in the animation block. if you cannot get it how you want it leave me specific instructions on exactly how you want it, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks, I might even just go for a popover view controller. I'm getting lots of clipping errors with the code you provided and my current layout. Could possibly be something to do with the arrangement of the layers, but I don't know enough about it to sort it out.

Comment: The "problem" is most likely due to the expansion the containerView goes through, and thus your view. See suggestions in my edit. Trust me you can make this work and its going to look great!

Comment: That is a brilliant idea. I've got a few new-found bugs to fix before I add any new functionality, but I'll give that a go once these are sorted. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did a rough code (not at all perfect) on this (hope it is what you are looking for). Have a look into it. I created a baseView and two flip views, after the first flip, I increased the frame size of baseView and added the second flip view on it.I am not an expert of Story Board, so I havent used it here.

[FlipTest](http://www.sendspace.com/file/kl6lew)

-anoop